# Messy database correction plan

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have 40 databases on the same schema but for 40 different clients and an asp.net client application sitting on top of the database.

The databases are in a serious mess in the sense that they do not have relationship constraints so there is lots of orphan data. I wanted some advise from someone who has dealt with something similar because obviously I can't go in and put constraints on everything in one go as it will simply crash agent jobs, SP etc

my plan so far is
1) Delete orphan data from large tables and monitor
2) Add primary keys and ensure naming conventions are right
3) Add relationships on a few tables and monitor for issues.

Comment: Roughly how many tables does each database contain and how long do you plan to support/work on this project?

Comment: its around 150 tables in total, they are not huge but I 12 months which is enough

Comment: If you are going to work on it for 12 months, then I would suggest making a db schema using `MySql Workbench` or similar tools. Once you get a clear picture for each db, you can go on with the changes you have mentioned. **Don't forget to take frequent backups.**